# How to add an integer to a fraction using classes in Python?

Tags: python, class, fractions

In the code I wrote, I managed to add fractions together, but I would also like to be able to add whole numbers to a fraction.

```
def gcd(denominator, numerator):
    if numerator == 0:
        return denominator
    else:
        return gcd(numerator, (denominator % numerator))

class Fraction:
    
    def __init__(self,numerator = 0, denominator = 1):

        self.numerator = int(numerator / gcd(abs(denominator),abs(numerator) ))
        self.denominator = int(denominator / gcd(abs(denominator),abs(numerator) ))
        if self.denominator < 0:
            self.denominator = abs(self.denominator)
            self.numerator = -1*self.numerator
        elif self.denominator == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError
        
    def __str__(self):
        if self.denominator == 1:
            return str(self.numerator)
        else:
            return str(self.numerator) + "/" + str(self.denominator)
    
    def __add__(self,other):
        if type(other) == int:
            other = Fraction(other,1)
            return self.add(other)
        else:
            
            return self.add(other)
    
    def add(self,other):
        result = Fraction()
        
        result.numerator = other.denominator * self.numerator + self.denominator * other.numerator
        result.denominator = other.denominator * self.denominator
        
        multiple = gcd(result.denominator,result.numerator)
        
        result.numerator = int(result.numerator / multiple)
        result.denominator = int(result.denominator / multiple)
        
        return result

p = Fraction(2,3)
q = Fraction(3,5)
r = (p + 1)

print(r)
```

At the moment this works for (fraction + integer) but not for (integer + fraction). I have already searched for some things, such as the use of `__radd__`, but when I use this the (integer + fraction) works, but the (fraction + integer) no longer works....

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Show your `__radd__` code properly formatted in the question and explain "no longer works" (show error message if one appears).

Comment: Your code worked for both cases i.e. `print(p + 1)` and `print(1 + p)` when I added `__radd__` method i.e. `def __radd__(self, other): return self.__add__(other)`

Comment: @DarrylG Thank you very much, I think it works now! When I used `__radd__` myself I completely replaced `__add__` with `__radd__`, but apparently that is not possible.

Comment: @yungCalculator--glad to help. Guess you realize you need both __add__ and __radd__.  You should add your corrected code as an answer to make it easier for others to find in the future (i.e. so they don't have to read throught the comments).